# Insert data from form to drupal database

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-8

pretty new to drupal and I am running into a problem trying to insert data into my database from a form.

The form itself is generated from js in my theme folder,

```
$('.register')
  .find('.title_block')
  .addClass('reg-details')
  .append('<div id="emailRegister" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"> 
    <span class="close">&times;</span><br><br><p>We have detected that you 
      are on a mobile device. It can 
      take up to 2 minutes to fill out the required profile.</p><p>If you 
      would like to finish this 
      profile at a later time, we can email it to you.</p><p>Otherwise, 
      select Close to proceed!</p> 
      <form method="post" action="/register.php" enctype="multipart/form- 
      data">First name:<br><input 
      type="text" class="emailFields" name="firstname" value=""><br>Last 
      name:<br><input type="text" 
      class="emailFields" name="lastname" value=""><br>Email:<br><input 
      type="email" 
      class="emailFields" id="regEmail" name="email"><br><input type="submit" 
      value="Submit"><br> 
      </form><button type="submit" id="closeModal" 
      style="background:grey">Close</button>')
  .insertBefore('.lms-main-container');
```

The action page is in the root of my folder

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 use Drupal\docebo_login\FormaNotification;

 $email = $fname = $lname = "";
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $fname = $_POST["firstname"];
 $lname = $_POST["lastname"];

 if ($email == "" || $fname == "" || $lname == "") {
   header("Location: http://example.com");
   exit();
 }

 $noti = new FormaNotification();

 $result = $noti->getRegister($fname, $lname, $email);

 $auth = array('api_key' => 'some=key=here');

 # The unique identifier for this smart email
 $smart_email_id = 'email-id';

 # Create a new mailer and define your message
 $wrap = new CS_REST_Transactional_SmartEmail($smart_email_id, $auth);
 $message = array(
     "To" => $email,
     "Data" => array(
         'variableName' => 'variableNameTestValue',
         'x-apple-data-detectors' => 'x-apple-data-detectorsTestValue',
         'href^="tel"' => 'href^="tel"TestValue',
         'href^="sms"' => 'href^="sms"TestValue',
         'owa' => 'owaTestValue',
         'role=section' => 'role=sectionTestValue',
         'style*="font-size:1px"' => 'style*="font-size:1px"TestValue',
     ),
 );

 # Add consent to track value
 $consent_to_track = 'no'; # Valid: 'yes', 'no', 'unchanged'

  # Send the message and save the response
 $result = $wrap->send($message, $consent_to_track);
 if ($result) {
   header("Location: /");
   exit();
 }
```

As you can see I call a function from my theme's modules here is the function

```
   public function getRegister($fname, $lname, $email) {

        return parent::insertRegister($fname, $lname, $email);
    }
```

Which Then passes the variables on to this function in its parent

```
 public function insertRegister($fname, $lname, $email) {
       db_set_active('docebo');
       $this->setConnection('dev-db');
      $result = $this->getConnection()->insert('register')
       ->fields([
         'fistName' => $fname,
         'lastName' => $lname,
         'email' => $email,
         'dateAdded' => REQUEST_TIME,
       ])
       ->execute();
       db_set_active();
     }
```

Now I could be naive but I thought that would be it. But When I submit the form all I get is an 500 error notice. When I remove the insert from the form action, the form works as expected.

I tried getting a better error message to help me out ie checking my settings.php to make sure error reporting was on verbose, even tring to set it in my ini.php or putting the

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

on the form action page itself and still get nothing. There also appears to be nothing in my logs as well. So I am pretty stumped. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: I do know of https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/

Unfortunately, this form and the the entire page the form is on is generated via javascript so I am not sure that it will work